# Is there any problem with this proof of relations?

Tags: relation, discrete-mathematics

Consider a relation R: A → A which is both symmetric and transitive.

The following proof shows that the relation is also reflexive: Take a ∈ A. If a ∼ b then b ∼ a by
symmetry, and hence a ∼ a by transitivity. Therefore, the relation is reflexive."

Is the proof correct or not?

I think it is incorrect. I think it should be "For every a ∈ A, there exists b ∈ B that a ~ b and b ~ a.", not just "Take a ∈ A". After that we can use symmetry and transitivity to prove it is reflexive. That is what I think.

Am I right? Or what is the correct answer and the reason? THANKS!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be posted on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Yes. I agree. I just made a mistake. Sorry!!

Comment: you are right, Incorrect proof ex: consider relation R= {(x,y),(y,x)(x,x),(y,y)} on S={x,y,z} is symmetric and transitive but not reflexive (z,z) is missing

Answer (score 2):

> Take a ∈ A. If a ∼ b then b ∼ a by symmetry, and hence a ∼ a by transitivity.

So far, so good

> Therefore, the relation is reflexive.

This is where the error is. To be reflexive, we require `a ~ a` regardless of whether `a ~ b`. This is the error.